# How to match date interval using DateDiff in php?

Tags: php, date, datediff

**[UPDATE:] Sorry, but I have to use months instead of years and the +1 days**

I have a table on DB with Classes and an interval of months (not years, sorry:).

```
       name   min_age   max_age
       A      14        16
       B      16        19
       ...
```

The user will be placed in a particular class based on his age and the present time.

The rule to place the user in a particular class is:
Class A: min_age 14 plus 1 day AND max_age 16
Class B: min_age 16 plus 1 day AND max_age 19
...

how can I create a IF to place/match the user on the right class based on his age?

Here is my code to calculate the date interval:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2019-04-16"); 
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-08-17"); 
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
return $interval;
```

Here is my IF structure:

```
if($interval->m >= min_age && $interval->m <= max_age) {
    // show Class
}
```

but I have to place the rule of "plus 1 day" for each class. Example: 14 months + 1 day == class A ...

Comment: The easiest way is going to be to convert their current age to # of months.  So age 8 is "96", age 8 plus 1 month is "97", etc.

Comment: Thanks! But I have to use months instead of years and the plus 1 would the a day (not month). Sorry about the mess! In this case, as there are certain months that have 31 or 28 ou 29 wouldn't be a little messy or imprecise converting it to days?

Comment: Months make it impossible to calculate with precision, because as you've noted, not all months are equal length.  You'd need to change your database to either use days or years.

Comment: Thanks @FoulFoot! I've considered these options, but even if I change to days, wouldn't I have the same problem?

Comment: Well, no, not if you’re storing their actual age in days.  If you only currently have their ages in months, you’re a bit screwed.  :(

Comment: Thanks! That was the case. I mean, I've stored the age in days and made the comparison.